# NA in time series handling?

Tags: r, time-series, na, imputation

I am dealing with a forecast of time series in R.  I have several questions:

1. I would like to ask how we can handle missing values in time series?
2. I guess we can somehow interpolate them?
3. Can you suggest some solution in R for this?

Comment: Check the `mice` package.

Comment: As addition to hpesoj626's answer: Be a little bit careful, mice does only work if you have a multivariate time-series (with more than 1 variable). Might make sense to use a package that is specialized especially in time-series imputation as suggested in Artem's answer.

Comment: You might get better results asking on http://stats.stackexchange.com since they'd be able to help you with the actual statistics of your problem, not just the programing parts of it

Answer (score 3):

One of the solutions `imputeTS` library.

```
library(imputeTS)

# amount of NA
table(is.na(tsAirgap))

# Kalman smoothing imputation (one of the best)
imp_tsAirgap <- na_kalman(tsAirgap)

# Imputed time-series, no NAs
table(is.na(imp_tsAirgap))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to delete the missing values and their corresponding time-stamps, you can also use the `na.remove` function within the `tseries` package.